# Append a local file to a remote file over ssh

Tags: ssh

I can use ssh or scp to append a remote file to a local file, but I cannot figure out how to do the reverse and append a local file to a remote server.

`ssh remote.server cat /path/to/file >> locale-file`

Works great (but not with globbing), but how do I reverse it?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
<localfile ssh remote.server 'cat >> remote_file'
```

This will send the contents of `localfile` to the `stdin` of `ssh`.

Comment: `ssh -t ...` The "-t" isn't helpful here, and it could cause the operation to fail. You're better off leaving it out. `ssh remote.server "cat..."`

Comment: yes, `ssh -t` causes an error (`Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.`), though in my case it still worked.

Comment: The `-` is not even necessary.

Comment: Better to use `-T`, i.e. not allocate any TTY at all.